# Auto POST Form on Interval is missing form field values

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a script that works fine when a button is used to post the form.  But when I convert the form to (auto)post on an interval, the form (field) values are missing when posted.
I know this has something to do with using the closest(form) as the button assists with closest (form) as a reference, but auto post on  Interval  has no reference for  closest (form). Any help is appreciated thanks.  By the way my form is on a sql while loop.

A)  is the script when used with  button.
B)  is the script when used with a Auto(post) on interval.

**The form)**

```
<form  class="updateform"  action="" method="" > 
<input type="hidden" class ="customerid"  name="" value="<?php echo $customerid?>">
<a   class ="test" >test</a>
<div class="update"> </div>
</form>
```

** A)**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
 
        var form = $(this).closest("form");
        var field1= form.find('.customerid').val();
   
        // Url to post to and Field name and content */          
        $.post('/test4.php', {customerid:field1},
        
         // Alert Success
         function(data){
        // Alerts the results to this Div
      form.find('.update').html(data);
            
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

** b)**

```
<script>
$(function() {
 var form = $(this).closest("form");
 var field1= $('.customerid').val();
  function update() {
      $.post("/test4.php",  {customerid:field1},
      function(data){
        $('.update').html(data); 
    });
  }
  setInterval(update, 3000);
  update();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because of the `.closest()` method in the second script. You are trying to select the form there which is closest to `this` up the tree. But in this case `this` will either be the scope of the function or the `window` object. Change it to a `jQuery` selector and select the correct form.

You can test this by yourself by either using [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) or the [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement to check what the values of the elements are in the developer tools of the browser. Get familiar with these guys, you'll need them a lot and are essential tools to even the most experienced developer.

If I may give a tip. Name your jQuery elements (the elements you select with `$('element')`) with a `$` prefix. This way you know by reading the variable what kind of value that variable has. Also giving your variables meaningful names makes it even more easy to read and understand. `field1` is generic, but `customerIdField` tells you what field it is.

```
$(function() {
  var $form = $('form.updateform');
  var $updateField = $form.find('.update')
  var $customerIdField = form.find('.customerid');
  var customerIdValue = $customerIdField.val();
  function update() {
    $.post("/test4.php",  {customerid: customerIdValue}, function(data) {
      $updateField.html(data); 
    });
  }
  setInterval(update, 3000);
  update();
});
```

Comment: Emiel , Thank you for the good Tip for naming elements and also for displaying your  possible solution very clearly. Thank you.   I will test it later and give feed back.